# Query for every 3 mins interval of time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with WORK_ORDER, DATE and other columns. I need a query to fetch the data for every 3 min interval of time based upon the DATE column.

Comment: Did you try something already? Do you have a beginning of a query?

Comment: What does "to fetch the data for every 3 min interval of time" mean? The query returns a result set, which is shaped according to the filters and calculations applied. Please clarify your requirement and back it up with some (minimized to demonstrate the issue) sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, you want to count the number of work orders in each three minute period then you can truncate the `DATE` column to the start of the minute (to zero the seconds component) and then subtract the minute component modulo 3 (which works as there are exact multiples of 3 minutes in an hour so you do not need to worry about overlapping the hour boundary) to get the `DATE` at the start of each three-minute interval; you can then `GROUP BY` that and aggregate:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC("DATE", 'MI')
       - MOD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST("DATE" AS TIMESTAMP)), 3)
         * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE AS date_grp,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       TRUNC("DATE", 'MI')
       - MOD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST("DATE" AS TIMESTAMP)), 3)
         * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
```

Which, for the sample data (with 10 rows at minute intervals):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (work_order, "DATE") AS
SELECT LEVEL, TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE * LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Outputs:

| DATE_GRP | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-16 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2023-05-16 00:03:00 | 3 |
| 2023-05-16 00:06:00 | 3 |
| 2023-05-16 00:09:00 | 2 |

*Note: `DATE` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an unquoted identifier; you either need to use a different identifier for the column or use quoted identifiers everywhere the identifier is used.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mBNmuAsv)